# Use Highcharts-ng with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, highcharts

For display the chart, y use the tipical way:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.highchartsNG = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },
        loading: false
    }
});>
```

But i want load the data from a remote json.

I tried using the method described in the official documentation, but with angular it does not work. I'm using highchart-ng but i dont know how to load remote JSON-Files.

I'm researching how to use $http.get but still i dont know how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: In the angular you have services and $http which allows to communicate ajax with your controler.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Data ofr your chart to be within a variable:

```
var chartData = [];
[...]
series: [{
     data: chartData
}],
[...]
```

Then you can use the $http-Service like the following:

```
$http.get('/PATH/TO/MY/JSON')
  .success(function(jsonData){
      // Do some remodeling of the jsonData if necessary, else just give it to the chart:
      chartData = jsonData;
  }
```

The `$http`-Service of Angular works promise based - this means that you provide the callback of the request within `.success` and `.error`-Functions. Its pretty good explained in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).